# Replacing a for loop related to a parameter inside function of two variables by numpy sum

Tags: function, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I am trying to speed up a function that can be minimally represented by:

```
import numpy as np

def simple_function(x, y, a1, a2, a3):
    return a1 + a2*x**2/(1 + a3*y**2)


def to_optimnize(x, y, a1, a2, a3, N):
    Sigma = 0
    for i in range(len(N)):
        yn = N[i]*y
        Sigma = Sigma + N[i]*simple_function(x, yn, a1, a2, a3)
    return Sigma


x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.linspace(0, 4, 200)

N = np.random.random((180,))
a1, a2, a3 = 1, 2, 3


X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
test = simple_function(X, Y, a1, a2, a3)
result = to_optimnize(X, Y, a1, a2, a3, N)
```

The for loop is mostly a cumulative sum, though I can not figure out how to use numpy here while keeping the 'vectorized' behavior allowing to call it using the grid resulting from `np.meshgrid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mostly seems to be a matter of getting the shapes for broadcasting correct. To understand what's going on here, note that given a 1-d array `a`, `a[None, :]` creates a 2-d array with a first dimension of length `1`. `a[:, None]` creates a 2-d array with a second dimension of length `1`.

```
def to_optimize_new(x, y, a1, a2, a3, n):
    n = n[None, None, :]
    y = y[:, :, None]
    x = x[:, :, None]
    yn = n * y
    series = n * simple_function(x, yn, a1, a2, a3)
    return series.sum(axis=2)
```

This gives correct results when tested with `np.allclose`:

```
>>> np.allclose(to_optimize_new(X, Y, a1, a2, a3, N), 
...             to_optimize(X, Y, a1, a2, a3, N))
True
```

This approach could be memory-intensive, since the results of all the operations are stored and summed at the very end. But for this example it works well.

By the way, if you have no reason for using `meshgrid` other than to enable broadcasting, then you can use the same reshaping trick to avoid the `meshgrid` call, like so:

```
def to_optimize_nomesh(x, y, a1, a2, a3, n):
    n = n[None, None, :]
    x = x[None, :, None]
    y = y[:, None, None]
    yn = n * y
    series = n * simple_function(x, yn, a1, a2, a3)
    return series.sum(axis=2)
```

If you want a fully generic function, just remove the reshaping commands entirely. This will work with scalar inputs.

```
def to_optimize_generic(x, y, a1, a2, a3, n):
    yn = n * y
    series = n * simple_function(x, yn, a1, a2, a3)
    return series
```

But if you want to use vector inputs, you have to give them the right shape *outside* the function and perform the sum after returning:

```
>>> np.allclose(
...     to_optimize_generic(x[None, :, None], 
...                         y[:, None, None], 
...                         a1, a2, a3, 
...                         N[None, None, :]).sum(axis=2), 
...     to_optimize(X, Y, a1, a2, a3, N))
True
```

You can tell which axis to sum based on which axis in `N` has the `:`.

```
>>> np.allclose(
...     to_optimize_generic(x[None, None, :], 
...                         y[None, :, None], 
...                         a1, a2, a3, 
...                         N[:, None, None]).sum(axis=0), 
...     to_optimize(X, Y, a1, a2, a3, N))
True
```

Comment: This does the job. Howerver, I am a bit concern with the loss of generality about the dimensions of `x` and `y`. While I mainly plot compute surfaces with this function, I also like to compute the values at a specific point (`x` and `y` are floats), or along a path (`x` and `y` are then 1D-numpy arrays). How can I adapt your answer for this ?

Comment: @Liris. By keeping careful track of your dimensions.

Comment: I guess I can not avoid testing the dimensions at the beginning and adapting the number of dimensions on length 1 when changing the shapes.

Comment: @Liris, it depends on what you mean. You *can* push that part of the work outside the function. See my second edit.